Wait for finish of queryProductDetailsAsync to display price of InApp product
I want to display on android button price of my InnApp product.
I use queryProductDetailsAsync to get price.
Issue is that when I assign price in button "binding.ButtonBuy.text = price" sometimes it don't show anything or wrong data. I suspect that its because queryProductDetailsAsync is Async and I should firstly wait for function to finish and than assing proper price.
I wonder why Timber.tag("Mik").d("\nPrice: " + price) is always displaying proper price but when assign to button its not always proper.
Can somebody help me to modify code properly to wait with "binding.ButtonBuy.text = price" when price is ready ?
class Zakupy : AppCompatActivity(), PurchasesUpdatedListener {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityZakupyBinding
    private lateinit var billingClient: BillingClient
    private var price: String = "?"    

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityZakupyBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build()

    billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                Timber.tag("Mik").d("BillingRespondCode-OK")

                val productList = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder().setProductList(ImmutableList.of(QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder().setProductId("add_free").setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP).build())).build()


                billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(productList) { billingResult,
                                                                      productDetailsList ->

                    val productDetails = productDetailsList[0]  // choose index zero because we had only 1 product
                    
                    price = productDetails.oneTimePurchaseOfferDetails?.formattedPrice.toString()
                        .filter { it.isDigit() || it == ',' || it == '.' } + " " + productDetails.oneTimePurchaseOfferDetails?.priceCurrencyCode

                    Timber.tag("Mik").d("\ncena: " + price)
                    binding.ButtonKup.text = price
                }


The above code is correct. All the code inside the lambda function is called only after the asynchronous task is complete. Maybe you are setting the TextView somewhere else in your code that you shouldn’t be.

Unrelated recommendation: you probably should not try to remove the currency from the String and tack it back on because the currency symbol’s proper position before or after the number varies by country.

Thanks for help @Tenfour04. I have debug it more and seems that real issue is with "binding.ButtonBuy.text = price" line. Sometimes (10%) its just don't work and not assign any value despite price is derived correctly. Not sure why. I am not modyfing it in another place. There is just default value "$".

Maybe you are binding multiple layouts under certain conditions and updating the outdated layout.

@Tenfour04 I have added more code in original question. Probably something wrong with this binding. Can You check ?

I don’t see a problem with the binding. However, you should not be working with the billing client directly in your activity unless you have configuration changes disabled. Otherwise there will be major issues when the screen rotates because you will be creating multiple billing client instances and leaking previous asynchronous tasks. Usually, a billing client should be interacted with through a singleton class.

@Tenfour04, thanks a lot:) I made BilingClient only once in Main Activity and is working now:) Great!!!
